# Calling Parent in OOP Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, oop

There is two class in model. I called both of it on view controller. The question it is when i want to use print on parent class it doesn't work?

this is my parent and child class in view controler :

```
     class shape {

        var area : Double?

        func calculateArea(valA: Double, valB :Double) {
            print("a")
        }

         func calculateArea(valA: Double) {

              print("b")
           }

        func save()

        {

        }

    }

class Triangle : shape {

    override func calculateArea(valA: Double) {
        print("c")
    }

}


class Rectangle : shape {

    override func calculateArea(valA: Double, valB: Double) {
        print("d")
    }

}
```

this is what i calling in view controler :

```
  var triangle : Triangle!

  var rectangle : Rectangle!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        triangle = Triangle()
  triangle.calculateArea(valA: 1.0)
        triangle.area = 12;
        triangle.save();


        rectangle = Rectangle()
        rectangle.calculateArea(valA: 2.3, valB: 1.2)
        rectangle.area = 23.5
        rectangle.save()
}
```

When i run it "a" and "b" doesn't print in parent class but "c" and "d" printed correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call super method from the overriding method, like

```
class Triangle : shape {
    override func calculateArea(valA: Double) {
        super.calculateArea(valA: valA)
        print("c")
    }
}
```

Think of this as if you want to *extend* the functionality of the super class then include a call to the overridden method but if you want *replace* the functionality in the super class then you don't include a call to super

Comment: Thank you so mush bro it Works .

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting to call super. This should work:

```swift
override func calculateArea(valA: Double) {
    super.calculateArea(valA)
    print("c")
}

override func calculateArea(valA: Double, valB: Double) {
    super.calculateArea(valA, valB)
    print("d")
}
```